# Dygraphs multiple y axes for same value

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm using barChartPlotter to show power (kWh) values for each day and it works great.

Now I would like to put price (kWh value * 0.08) on y2 axis. So that on y axis I have kWh and on the right y2 axis price (but to have only 1 column). I tried adding extra y2 into axes option, but I cannot get it work without adding another series.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not. You have to add another series.